# WireMock per test-case setup hanging on second test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, freeze

I'm using WireMock to test a Spring Boot web app that, itself uses Jetty, though on different ports.

What I'm seeing is that, if I use the basic Rule configuration:

```
@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(8006);
```

and I use `stubFor` in a `@Before` method, and then immediately follow that up with a call to the stubbed URL (via Spring's `RestTemplate`), the first test case works without a hitch, but then the second test case hangs. The bit of relevant stack trace is:

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f60a4009000 nid=0xb8d0 runnable [0x00007f60abcec000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    - locked <0x00000000f33e8d00> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:688)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:767)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
    - locked <0x00000000f33da7c8> (a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:397)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:33)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.getHttpStatusCode(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:502)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.put(RestTemplate.java:381)
```

If I instead use the static methods shown on the 'Getting Started' page, everything works fine. I'm fine with going with the static method so that WireMock is started/stopped once per class, but for my own edification I would love to know why the other case isn't working as expected.

UPDATE: Just noticed that after ~200 seconds, the test fails with:

```
nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
```

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 1):

In my project I use random port for WireMock
@Rule WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(Options.DYNAMIC_PORT)

And it is working perfect. It's better solution because after change you can run tests in parallel:)